# Node.JS / Express: Connecting two endpoints together

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

So I'm working on a project in node and Express, and while I've gotten a bit of experience playing around with it already and through a few other frameworks, I'm still trying to figure out the best way to connect two of them together.

I have set up models and databases using POSTGRES to hold the ids and connecting tables.

Here is what I have so far:

#### GET User

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', function(req, res) {
User.findOne({ where: { phone: req.params.id }}).then(function(user) {
  if (!user) {
    ////////   Create a user
    var newUser = User.build({ phone: req.params.id});
    newUser.save().then(function(user) {
      var json = userJson(user);
      res.json(json)
    }).catch(function(err) {
      res.json(err);
    });
  } else {
    //////// Existing user
    var json = userJson(user);
    json.events = []
    Event.findAll({ where: { user_id: user.id }}).then(function(events) {
      for( var i in events) {
        json.events.push({
          id: events[i].dataValues['id'],
          hosting: events[i].dataValues['hosting'],
          attending: attending[i].dataValues['attending'],
          invites: events[i].dataValues['invites']
        })
      }
      res.json(json)
    })
  }
})
});
```

#### GET Events

```
app.get('/api/events/:id', function(req, res) {
Event.findOne({ where: { id: req.params.id }}).then(function(event) {
  // console.log('-------------',event);
    var item = {
      id:             event.dataValues['id'],
      event_name:     event.dataValues['event_name'],
      event_at:       event.dataValues['event_at'],
      address:        event.dataValues['address'],
      description:    event.dataValues['description'],
      image:          event.dataValues['image'],
      categories: []
    }
      res.json(item);
  })
});
```

#### POST Events

```
app.post('/api/events', function(req, res) {
var newEvent = Event.build({
                             user_id:     req.body.user_id,
                             event_name:  req.body.event_name,
                             event_at:    req.body.event_at,
                             address:     req.body.address,
                             description: req.body.description,
                             image:       req.body.image
                                                                });


    newEvent.save().then(function(event) {
      res.redirect('/api/events/'+event.id);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // console.log(err);
      return res.json({error: 'Error adding new event'});
    })

  });
```

#### Model: event_invite.js

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 return sequelize.define('event_hostings', {
  user_id           : DataTypes.INTEGER,
  event_id          : DataTypes.INTEGER
  }
 );
}
```

I know that there is a way to connect the two together, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to interconnect the two when a USER creates an EVENT, and able to have it connect back to the user and recognize them as the creator.

Any advice or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you're asking.  One comment about your code as-is, though, it's generally not a good idea to modify anything (e.g. create a new user) based on a GET request.  There are a number of reasons for that, but the main one is that it's not what it's intended for.  POST (or PUT) should create, GET should just get/query.

Comment: @Paul You're right, this is more of a workaround for now that will be changed later.  I know that post is used to send info and get is used to pull info, but at the moment I'm just trying to figure out the best way to connect the two.

Comment: Connect the post and the get?